# Using CASE column in GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need help understanding why I cant GROUP BY a field in the select list that uses CASE

Here's the query

```
select 
    CASE WHEN COUNT(AB9_NUMOS) = 0 THEN 'P' ELSE 'E' END AS result,
    AAG_DESCRI,
    count(AB6_STATUS) as count
from AB6010
    left join AB7010 on AB7_FILIAL = AB6_FILIAL and AB7_NUMOS = AB6_NUMOS and AB7010.D_E_L_E_T_ = ' '
    left join AAG010 on AAG_CODPRB = AB7_CODPRB and AAG010.D_E_L_E_T_ = ' ' 
    left join AB9010 on AB9_FILIAL = AB6_FILIAL AND AB9_NUMOS = AB6_NUMOS+'01' and AB9010.D_E_L_E_T_ = ' '
where 
    ab6010.D_E_L_E_T_ = ' '
    and AB6_FILIAL = '01'
    and AB6_STATUS = 'A'
group by result, AAG_DESCRI
```

In this query i'm trying to categorize my rows in the table AB6010,
Each row in AB6010(service orders) could have none or N references at AB9010 (if my AB6010 row has any reference in the AB9010 means my service order is already being executed). So what i'm trying to do is:

If AB6010 has 0 references in AB9010, then its status is 'P'

If AB6010 has 1 or more references in AB9010 then its status should be 'E'

then I'd like to group by this status, and by AAG_DESCRI (which means which type of service order it is), and show how many AB6010 type X (aag_descri) rows are 'P' and how many are 'E'. But when I run the query I get the following error

```
Invalid column name 'result'.
```

My expected result should be something like

```
result     AAG_DESCRI                     count
---------- ------------------------------ -----------
E          CORTE A PLASMA                 7
E          CORTE E DOBRA                  31
E          FABRICACAO                     7
E          MANUTENCAO                     4
E          RETORNO/GARANTIA               3
P          CORTE A PLASMA                 3
P          CORTE E DOBRA                  10
P          FABRICACAO                     3
P          MANUTENCAO                     1
P          RETORNO/GARANTIA               8
```

Comment: You can't use a select alias in a group by.  How can it use something that is not even known yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can benefit from `cte` like below.

```
;with cte (result,AB6_NUMOS,AAG_DESCRI) as (
   select 
            CASE WHEN COUNT(AB9_NUMOS) = 0 THEN 'P' ELSE 'E' END AS result,
            AB6_NUMOS,
            AAG_DESCRI
   from AB6010
            left join AB7010 on AB7_FILIAL = AB6_FILIAL and AB7_NUMOS = AB6_NUMOS and AB7010.D_E_L_E_T_ = ' '
            left join AAG010 on AAG_CODPRB = AB7_CODPRB and AAG010.D_E_L_E_T_ = ' ' 
            left join AB9010 on AB9_FILIAL = AB6_FILIAL AND AB9_NUMOS = AB6_NUMOS+'01' and AB9010.D_E_L_E_T_ = ' '
   where 
            ab6010.D_E_L_E_T_ = ' '
            and AB6_FILIAL = '01'
            and AB6_STATUS = 'A'
            group by AB6_NUMOS,AAG_DESCRI
)
select result, AAG_DESCRI, count(AB6_NUMOS) as count
from cte
group by result, AAG_DESCRI
order by result,AAg_DESCRI
```

Comment: I tried it, but i get the following: 
"Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause."

Comment: `Column 'AAG010.AAG_DESCRI' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: I modified your answer and got the result I wanted, thanks @Eray Balkanli

Answer (score 1):

Use a sub query

```
select 
from (select AAG_DESCRI, COUNT(AB9_NUMOS) as c1, COUNT(AB6_STATUS) as c2 
           , CASE WHEN COUNT(AB9_NUMOS) = 0 THEN 'P' ELSE 'E' END AS result 
      from from AB6010 
      group by AAG_DESCRI 
     ) t
```